# map giving some ambiguous value

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers

The output expected is "2a3b3c4d3l4z" but 
i'm getting:12a3b3c4d3l4z.

Why the extra "1" is coming in the output?

```
char ipstr[] = "aabbbcccddddzzzzlll";
    cout<<"size of string:"<<sizeof(ipstr)<<endl;
    num = 0;
    map<char, int> ms;
    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(ipstr);i++){
        if(ipstr[i] == ipstr[i+1])
            num++;
        else{
            ms[ipstr[i]] = num+1;
            num = 0;
        }
    }

    for(auto it = ms.begin();it != ms.end();it++){
        cout<<it->second<<it->first;
    }
    cout<<endl;
```

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? 2) `ipstr[i+1]` is undefined behavior due to the out-of-bounds access. 3) You do know, that string literals are terminated with a `\0` character?

Comment: First of all sizeof is not a best idea to get the size of a string. Also, in a for loop you get over the bounds. Replace the condition with i < strlen(ipstr) - 1

Comment: make it simple. try 1 character.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes are correct. The terminated char value is getting printer here as 1.Is strlen will make it work fine? Whats the way to get rid of it?

Comment: @KirillKorolev yes, will change to strlen(), thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra `1` is the printout of the entry `{'\0', 1}` caused by taking the trailing `'\0'` into the loop. The `\0` is not printable, therefore you see only `1`.

Answer (score 2):

You evaluated your string length including '\0' character (it can be ambigious that string ends with this one). Then in a for loop you added '\0' to the map. But what does it mean to print null character. That's why you have 1 and a whitespace at the beginning.

```
char ipstr[] = "aabbbcccddddzzzzlll";
int n = strlen(ipstr);
cout << "size of string:" << n << endl;
int num = 0;
map<char, int> ms;

for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (ipstr[i] == ipstr[i + 1])
        num++;
    else {
        ms[ipstr[i]] = num + 1;
        num = 0;
    }
}

for (auto it = ms.begin(); it != ms.end(); it++) {
    cout << it->second << it->first;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<strlen(ipstr);i++){...} it works fine... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sameerpradhan did you that, you could also accept someones answer if it did help you to understand or solve your problem?

Comment: @Kirill Korolev: you haven't answered his question. *Why the extra "1" is coming in the output?*

Comment: That answer solves OP's problem, but does not answer the question '_Why_ the extra "1" is coming in the output?'